# A malware indexed 260000 bad url in google ! How can i force to de index them?

Tags: google-index, malware

The website `www.example.es` had a malware attack a few months ago. This malware managed to google thousands of fake urls. Typing "site: nolter.es" in google, 260,000 results appear, all of them with Chinese, Japanese characters, ...

Two weeks ago I removed the website completely and installed a temporary clean website (while we develop a new website). With G.Search Console I indexed the new home, create the new "sitemap" (`http://www.example.es/sitemap.xml`) and robots.txt.

However, today 260,000 false urls continue to appear indexed in google.
How can I remove all those urls from google indexing?

Comment: It seems you are using Apache. What format are your legitimate URLs - what characters are permitted in your legitimate URLs? (It's probably easier to only "allow" permitted URLs and "remove" the rest, rather than "removing" URLs that are not allowed - which is probably more varied and complex to match.)

Comment: See also: [Hacked website had it's SEO compromised, after recovery, google still index new corrupted URLs](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103629/hacked-website-had-its-seo-compromised-after-recovery-google-still-index-new) and [Remove hacked url from google index not working](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125583/remove-hacked-url-from-google-index-not-working)

Comment: It can take Google far longer than two weeks to deal with hundreds of thousands of bad URLs.    It could take months before Google removes all of them from the index.

Comment: Thanks for your comments !